# html5 input error message

Tags: jquery, html, forms, error-handling

I've got an Admin template page for adding staff. The page design is such where header (on top) and navigation (on left) is position fixed. So content area (the rest area, where form is given to add staff) goes behind of header on scrolling down.

Initially, there was problem that on clicking submit button the input field and respective error message both were lying back of header area. Which I managed to bring back in front or content area using following jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('#submt-form').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('input:invalid').offset().top-150}, 'slow');

    });
</script>
```

Now the issue is that while input field comes back to content area with above jquery code, the html 5 error message on respective field takes some time (few seconds) to shift back, to the appended position of input field.

Is there any way to make error message move alongwith respective input field.

Comment: You didn't declared the click event inside the document ready function..

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to input element's 'invalid' event triggered after validation but before display of invalidation UI.